# Prevent Auto-Format DriveApi 3 Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Using the Drive API3, I'm looking for a way to make a copy of a CSV file in Google Sheets format, without having to convert the text to numbers, nor the functions and dates as it can be proposed in the Google Sheets menu:

File>Import>(Select your CSV file)> Untick "Convert text to number, dates and formula".

At the moment, I've got something such as :

```
function convert(){
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1234');
      var resource = { title : "Title", mimeType : MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,parents : [{id: file.getParents().next().getId()}],}

      Drive.Files.copy(resource,file.getId())
}
```

To illustrate my example : I've got a text in my CSV file "2021-25-03", if I run my macro, the new spreadsheet will automaticaly format my text to a Date and that's not my goal.

TFR.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations as the image?

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a setting in the API or in Apps Script to prevent the automatic conversion of numbers and dates, but we can build a script to work around this.  Two tools are useful:

1. Apps Script's [`Utilities.parseCsv()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv) method, which will build a 2D array of the values in the CSV file (as pure text--it does not interpret numbers and dates).
2. The fact that Google Sheets interprets any value starting with a single quote `'` as text.  This is true whether the value is entered in the UI or programmatically.

So the overall strategy is:

1. Copy the file as you are doing (or just create a new blank file, as we will write the values to it).
2. Parse the CSV values and prepend a `'` to each one.
3. Write these modified values to the sheet.

Something like this:

```
function convert(){
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById(CSV_FILE_ID);
      // Create the copy:
      var resource = { title : "Title", mimeType : MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,parents : [{id: file.getParents().next().getId()}],}

      var sheetsFile = Drive.Files.copy(resource,file.getId())
      
      // Parse the original csv file:
      var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString())
      // csv is a 2D array; prepend each value with a single quote:
      csv.forEach(function(row){
        row.forEach(function(value, i){
          row[i] = "'" + value
        })
      })
      // Open the first (and only) sheet in the file and overwrite the values with these modified ones:
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetsFile.id).getSheets()[0]
      sheet.getRange(1,1,csv.length, csv[0].length).setValues(csv)
}
```